# Problem with HibernatePersistanceProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Got a problem with `HibernatePersistanceProvider` in `persistance.xml`

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
```

Error: `'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider' is not assignable to 'javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider,jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider'`

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: @tmsblgh yet, but I don't remember how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Jakarta Persistence 3.0 or 3.1, you will have to use Hibernate 6+.

Comment: I am using Hibernate 6.1.4, but got that error again.

Comment: How are you bootstrapping Hibernate i.e. how do you create the `PersistenceProvider`. Note that JPA 3+ is only supported since Spring 3